# Sharing a home with divorced spouse

Tags: divorce

Is it ok for a divorced couple to temporarily (on vacation for example) share a home, not alone but with grown children?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yichud

Comment: המגרש את אשתו לא ישרה עמה לא במבוי ולא בחצר אם היה מבוי של שניהם הופך פתחו לצד אחד ואם היתה חצר של שניהם מפנה זה מפני זה ומפנה אשה מפני איש בד"א בזמן שנשאו והכהנת אע"ג שלא נשאו בד"א מן הנשואין אבל מן האירוסין לא וכן החולץ ליבמתו לא יפנה מפני שאין לבו גס בה
(Cited from Masechet Semachot Chapter 2)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Sara and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: The law should logically be even stricter than for people who don't know each other. The familiarity leads to less barriers between them, making it easier to sin. If you are asking the question for a real case though, you should ask a Rabbi though

Answer (score 2):

[Shulchan Aruch, Even HaEzer 119:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.119.7):

> מי שגירש אשתו מן הנשואין לא תדור עמו בחצר שמא יבואו לידי זנות ואם היה
> כהן לא תדור עמו במבוי וכפר קטן נידון כמבוי. הגה ואם נשאת לאחר אפי'
> בישראל לא תדור עמו במבוי (טור) וכל זה במבוי סתום אבל במבוי מפולש שדרך
> רבים עובר ביניהם מותרים לדור (ב"י בשם הר"ן שכ"כ בשם התו') אם רה"ר
> מפסיק בין בתיהם (הגהות אשירי פ"ב דכתובות) אפי' אין בכל העיר שום יהודי
> רק הם לבדם שרי (תה"ד סי' רמ"ג) גירשה משום שאסורה עליו אפי' לא נשאת
> אסור לדור עמה כאלו נשאת לאחר (א"ז):
>
> One who divorced his wife from the marriage cannot live with her in
> the [same] courtyard [because] maybe they will come to impropriety.
> And if he is a Kohen, she should not live with him in the [same]
> passageway. A small village has the same law as a passageway. Rem"a:
> And if she married someone else, even a Yisrael, she should not live
> with him in the [same] passageway (Tur). And all this is [talking
> about] a closed passageway. But in a more open passageway through
> which many people pass, they are permitted to dwell (Beit Yoseif in
> the name of the Ran who wrote it in the name of Tosaphot). If public
> property separates between their houses (Haghot Ashri Ketubot Ch. 2)
> even if they are the only Jews in the city, it is permitted (Terumat
> HaDeshen Siman 243). If he divorced her because she was forbidden to
> him, even if she did not [re]marry, he is forbidden to dwell with her,
> as though she married someone else (Or Zarua).

Comment: The sources everyone is quoting is that generally the exes should have some separation. The question title sounds like it's asking about "in general", but the details are asking about temporary space. I'm not aware of sources about temporary situations, beyond the usual rules of chaperones for "seclusion."

Comment: Why should there be any difference? This Halacha appears four times throughout Even HaEzer in various contexts. Assur is assur.